# Is there a simple way to achieve something similar to `x[,c:=mean(a), by=b]$c`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

```
> x <- data.table(a=1:10, b=rep(1:2, 5))
> x
     a b
 1:  1 1
 2:  2 2
 3:  3 1
 4:  4 2
 5:  5 1
 6:  6 2
 7:  7 1
 8:  8 2
 9:  9 1
10: 10 2
> x[,c:=mean(a), by=b]
> y <- x$c
> y
 [1] 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6
```

Ultimately, I am interested in `y` as a vector, and I don't want to add `c` to the `data.table`. Is there an easier way to get `y` from the original `x`?

The problem arises when I tried to apply different weights to different group in a histogram.

```
# here weight would be the same for all colour, but I wish they differ.
geom_freqpoly(aes(colour=group, weight=mean(y)), binwidth=1)
```

Comment: If you're using `ggplot`, why not just attach that column to your data argument? `ggplot(data=Data[,c:=mean(a),by=b],...) + geom_freqpoly(aes(weight=c, ...))`

Comment: @SeñorO I don't want to change the data.table...

Comment: Then do `copy(Data)[,c:=mean(a),by=b]`

Comment: Why don't you want to change the data.table?

Comment: @SeñorO `x[, rep(mean(a), length(a)), by=b]$V1` would at least not copy the whole data.table.

Comment: @Roland that's actually not the same as what OP wants

Comment: @eddi You are right. The order is different. But I don't really understand why this is needed. They could just add `c` to the data.table afterall.

Comment: @Roland agreed, adding is the way to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> with(x, ave(a, b, FUN=mean) )
 [1] 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6
```

Just to let the data.table experts know, I am aware that this may not scale well to multi-million record datasets and I am appreciative of the other posts on this topic. I've been using data.table to good effect on my larger analyses. It was only because of an expressed desire for simplicity and non-modification of the data argument that I posted.

Comment: 1. `with(x, ave(a, b, FUN=function(x) { ... }))`; `FUN` will have access to those variables in `x`; 2. If you _really_ need a faster factor, see [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/fast-factor-generation/)

Comment: @colinfang: If you need to modify the behavior of the function sent to the FUN argument of `ave` you will need to build an anonymous function that takes an "x" argument. It would be difficult to do that within `ave` because the only thing that gets passed in is the values of "a" within categories of "b" so you cannot build factors very well, since there would be no way to know the other levels.

Comment: @KevinUshey: Thank you for the link to an Rcpp implementation of factors. But on the first point, I am getting confused by the use of "x" as the environment and "x" as the formal parameter for the function. I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: Nvm, I figured out how to do it. Basically I learned from how `ave` works and use `mapply + split + levels <-` to construct my own `ave`

Comment: @DWin Sorry, my comment was in response to something colinfang originally commented and then deleted. But you're right, I was being sloppy on 1, and you made the same point clearer next anyhow :)

Answer (score 3):

you can daisy-chain the `"["` operator:

```
x[, c := mean(a), by=b][, c]
# [1] 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6
```

The result from `"[.data.table"` is itself a data.table, so you can just add another one right after it.

---

I just noticed the comments about not wanting to modify x.  Notice that somehow you need to recycle the vector `c`.  R normally handles this for you.  If you want to do it manually, use:

```
 x[, list(c=mean(a)), by=b][, rep(c, length(x$a)/length(c))]
 # [1] 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6
```

---

As for the motivation in not modifying `x`, notice that there is almost negligible overhead in assigning a column and then dropping it later with `x[, c := NULL]`  so perhaps temporarily modifying the DT is the way to go.

---

As per @Frank's requests, here is a simple benchmark: 
With 100 elements, `by` is faster.  But the speed diminishes quickly

```
# The call used for benchmarking is as follows: 
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(B = as.vector(by(x$a,x$b,mean)[as.character(x$b)]), 
               D = x[, list(c=mean(a)), by=b][, rep(c, length(x$a)/length(c))]
               )



# medium sized x
N <- 1e4
x <- {set.seed(1); data.table(a=1:(N), b=sample(5, N, TRUE), key="b")}

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
    B 6.150740 6.284466 6.403332 7.790877 10.339314   100
    D 1.268631 1.337959 1.441184 1.525279  2.963625   100
```

Comment: Yeah, it's very fast to add and then remove c, relative to other data.table operations for this. However, when I benchmark the example given, mrip's wins by a pretty wide margin. Maybe you should/could illustrate with a larger example?

Comment: @Frank just rbind `x` a few times and try again - comparing run times of a few microseconds to each other is not very meaningful

Comment: Ricardo, I'm pretty sure OP's `x[...]$c` version is faster than doing `x[...][,c]`

Comment: @eddi Ok, it caught up at length 1280: `microbenchmark(
 doti={y<-x[,list(mean(a),.I), by=b][order(.I)]$V1},
 makedel={y<-x[, c := mean(a), by=b]$c;x[,c:=NULL]},
 bychar={y<-by(x$a,x$b,mean)[as.character(x$b)]}
)`

Comment: if we are really talking about data as small as 1K, 3K etc.  then it doesnt matter.  Use whichever syntax is more convenient for you.

Comment: @eddi, notice that I am not benchmarking against the line that modifies the data.table but rather against the one that repeats the column

Comment: all(B == D) is false; and they match exactly 1/5th of the time. Your rep trick in the second set of brackets only worked when column b was alternating, I guess...?

Comment: OP is looking for "simple", not fast.

Comment: @SeñorO agreed, and I think OP already has both in their title

Comment: @SeñorO, you're right.  Simple to me, is the first line at the top.  Adding the column to the data.table.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I think you missed my earlier comment -- your solution, "D", does not seem to work generically; compare B to D from your simulated data.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of doing it without modifying the original `data.table`, but imo that's an entirely artificial and unnecessary constraint, i.e. you have the best solution already.

```
x[, list(.I, mean(a)), by = b][order(.I), V2]
#[1] 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6

# or for faster ordering
setkey(x[, list(.I, mean(a)), by = b], .I)$V2
```

Comment: Hey eddi, have a look at the `keyby` argyment in  `[`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta sorry that's a bit too cryptic...?

Answer (score 1):

For this specific example, `by(x$a,x$b,mean)[as.character(x$b)]` should work.  I don't quite understand the histogram question, so I can't tell if this will generalize the way you want.

Comment: note that the OP is referencing `data.table`, so while this will work it does miss the point

Comment: How does it miss the point?  The OP wanted a simple solution that doesn't modify the data table.

Comment: data.table will be fast, `by` will be slow in comparison. Let's assume that data.table is used for its efficiency.

Comment: sorry, mrip, I did not mean my comment in an offensive manner.  `data.table` has several builtin efficiencies, including a `by` operator as part of its extraction operator. These leverage the fact that the data.table is often sorted.  When one calls `by` on a `data.table` many of those efficiencies are lost.  Have a search through many of the past answers here on SO for more info.